If any two of the circumcenter, incenter, orthocenter, and centroid are the same point, is the triangle equilateral?
Circumcenter- the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of a triangle, from which the length to each of the vertices is equal.
Incenter- the intersection of the angle bisectors of a triangle, which is also equidistant to each of the sides.
Orthocenter- the intersection of the altitudes of  a right triangle.
Centroid- the intersection of the medians of a triangle. The centroid splits the median into a 2:1 ratio of the length from the vertex to centroid: the length from the centroid to the opposite side. The medians divide the triangle into six smaller triangles of equal area.
I have solved two of the six scenarios (circumcenter-incenter, circumcenter-orthocenter, circumcenter-centroid, incenter-orthocenter, incenter-centroid, orthocenter-centroid): incenter-centroid and orthocenter-centroid.
For incenter-centroid, if $ABC$ is the given triangle, with point I as the point that is both the incenter and centroid, let $AI$ hit $BC$ at $S$. Since $AS$ passes through the incenter, it is an angle bisector. So, through the Angle Bisector Theorem, $AB/AC=SB/SC$. $AS$ must also be a median since it passes through the centroid, so $SB=SC$. Therefore, $AB/AC=SB/SC=1$, so $AB=AC$. $BI$ can then be extended to hit $AC$ at $T$, and similarly use $BT$ to show that $AB=AC$ so $AB=AC=BC$.
For orthocenter-centroid, let $H$ be the point that is both the centroid and the orthocenter in triangle $ABC$, and let $AH$ hit $BC$ at $X$. $AX$ must be both a median and an altitude since it passes through $H$. So, $AX$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and $BX=XC$. Since $AX=AX$, $\angle AXB=\angle AXC=90$ degrees, and $BX=XC$ so triangles $AXB$ and $AXC$ are congruent by $SAS$. Therefore, corresponding sides $AB$ and $AC$ are equal. Similarly, let $BH$ meet $AC$ at $Y$, and use $BY$ to prove that $BA=BC$, so that $AB=AC=BC$.
I understand that in an equilateral triangle, the circumcenter, incenter, orthocenter, and centroid are the same point, but how do you prove each of the six scenarios?

You should add more details: what are the definitions of the objects you mention in the title and what have you tried? It's also not good practice to only have your questions written in the title

Euler line allows you to solve orthocentre-circumcentre and circumcentre-centroid.

Perhaps, it would be easier to prove first the following fact: if in a triangle $ABC$ a point $D\in BC$ is such that $AD$ is both $x$ and $y$ where $x,y$ are two distinct elements of the set ${\textrm{median}, \textrm{altitude}, \textrm{angle bissector}}$, then $AB=AC$. These are quite classsical facts.
